# Problems hovering over ChartJS bar chart after being redrawn

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS with KnockoutJS and I'm having some problems sorting one of my bar charts.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/norbiu/aqa8w19d/

After hitting the sort button on top, the bar chart is redrawn correctly, but if I try hovering over the right side of the chart, it jumps back to the original order of the bars. Removing the mouse will return the bars to the corect order.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here's my update function:

```
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  var ctx = element.getContext('2d'),
    type = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
    data = ko.toJS(allBindings.get('chartData')),
    options = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get('chartOptions')) || {};

  if (chart) {
    chart.destroy();
    delete chart;
  }

  if (Object.keys(data).length != 0) {
    var chart = new Chart(ctx)[type](data, options);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your `chartType` binding handler to make it clear previously created charts before creating new one. Otherwise hovering areas of new charts will interfere with those from old chart.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chartType = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        if (!allBindings.has('chartData')) {
            throw Error('chartType must be used in conjunction with chartData and (optionally) chartOptions');
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var ctx = element.getContext('2d'),
        type = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
        data = ko.toJS(allBindings.get('chartData')),
        options = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get('chartOptions')) || {};

      if (chart) {
        console.debug(chart)
        chart.destroy();
        delete chart;
      }

      if (Object.keys(data).length != 0) {
        // destroy old chart
        var self = ko.bindingHandlers.chartType;
        self.chart && self.chart.destroy();
        // create new
        var chart = new Chart(ctx)[type](data, options);
        self.chart = chart;
      }
    },
    chart: null
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqa8w19d/1/

**Update**

Yes, the above handler stores the current chart inside of its *definition* so all *instances* of `chartType` binding share the same property `ko.bindingHandlers.chartType.chart`. The problem may be solved by storing every chart object separately for every bound element (e.g. as `<canvas>` element user property):

```
if (Object.keys(data).length != 0) {
    // destroy old chart
    element.chart && element.chart.destroy();
    // create new
    var chart = new Chart(ctx)[type](data, options);
    element.chart = chart;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aqa8w19d/3/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your solution works for a single chart on a page, but unfortunately I have multiple charts that load at different times as soon as data comes in. Here's another example http://jsfiddle.net/norbiu/aqa8w19d/2/ - all 3 charts load just fine on page load, but when I click the "add new data" button to simulate an update to the first chart, the last chart on the page always disappears. Clicking the sort button brings it back, but I'm trying to figure out what's causing it to dissapear.